# how to compare values with database values

Tags: android

im insertinguser installed app package name in database using below code and is insert sucessfully show me in log now i want to compare system install apped with this database values and display only that value that are in dataase so how do i compare?? what i wirte in this bracket      if ( ((p.packageName).equals("db.list???"))

```
    DatabaseHandler db;

                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        String Standard = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
         String id= url.substring(Standard .length(), url.indexOf("&"));
         db.addContact(new Contact(id));


  public class FunActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

     DatabaseHandler db;


                          private List<App> loadInstalledApps(boolean includeSysApps) {
  List<App> apps = new ArrayList<App>();

  // the package manager contains the information about all installed apps
  PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

  List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);    






     for(int i=0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
     PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
     if ( ((p.packageName).equals("db.list???"))  //what i write here
     App app = new App();
     app.setTitle(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
     app.setPackageName(p.packageName);
     app.setVersionName(p.versionName);
     app.setVersionCode(p.versionCode);
     CharSequence description = p.applicationInfo.loadDescription(packageManager);
     app.setDescription(description != null ? description.toString() : "");
     apps.add(app);
```

Comment: i folow this tutorial  http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: pplease help me how do i compare system install applictaions with database  values?

Comment: Please edit this post with code indentation. Its horrid now.

Answer (score 0):

to get list from database

add this method in your Database Handler

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllApps() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM table";
     ArrayList<String> apps = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            apps.add(cursor.getString("your column name"));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return list
    return apps;
}
```

first Get the list from the database and add to the `Arraylist`
then compare your app name with them

```
arraylist = dbHelper.getAllApps();
```

in your `if ( ((p.packageName).equals("db.list???"))`
replace with

```
 if (arraylist.contains(p.packageName))
    {
       add();
    }
    else
    {
     donothing();
    }
```

Comment: no i want to compare with database check if value is in database

Comment: i want to show only thats package name which are exist in database

Comment: ow to get liost from database

Comment: how to get list form database help me plzzz

Comment: i check value is save in database i check log cat but now i want to compare system install app with database how i compare them???

Comment: thnx but im confuse u mean i used only 1 list in my code which get values form database? remove  system app list??  please edit my code plzz

Comment: what values have you stored in the database?

Comment: package name of application which user install form googleplay store is install sucessfully ijust wants to cpmpare them with system install application packages and display only that applictaion inlist which are in database

Comment: ur code show bugs    The method getWritableDatabase() is undefined

Comment: have you put that method inside `DatabaseHelper` and does your `DatabaseHelper` class extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and

Comment: is extend                    extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: ssee my this post   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270701/how-to-compare-database-insert-values-with-other-values

Comment: have u seen mmy new posy micheal//